# Why do we assume that the solutions to the differential equation y''=-ky are sines and cosines?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Why do we assume that the solutions to the second order differential equation of the form

$$y''=-ky$$

are sines and cosines? Just by inspection it seems pretty obvious that this is the case given that the only difference between $y$ and its second derivative is a negative constant. However, is there a formal way to show that sines and cosines are well-suited solutions to the differential equation?

Comment: $\left \{ \sin, \cos \right \}$ is an orthogonal system so every solution to this equation will be a linear combination of them.

Comment: I recommend reading this and the preceding few sections: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ComplexRoots.aspx

Comment: @Berograd If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks for the help!

Comment: We do not assume, but we establish it. If someone says that we assume this, then most probably he/she is not aware of the proof. You can see the proof and development of circular functions based on this approach in this [blog post](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2016/03/theories-of-circular-functions-part-3.html).

Comment: In the case $k>0$, that is, although also the case $k < 0$ can be written using $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, when you have an equation with constant coefficients, you assume that $e^{rx}$ is a solution because $e^{rx}$ has the amazing property that its derivative is $re^{rx}$ which then helps you obtain a polynomial, which is called the characteristic polynomial. In other words, suppose that your equation is:

$$a_ny^{(n)}+a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)}+\cdots+a_1y'+a_0y=g(x)$$

You will first try to solve it for the homogeneous case which is easier, i.e. the RHS is $0$.

Now, suppose that $e^{rx}$ is a solution. You will get:

$$(a_nr^{n}+a_{n-1}r^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1r+a_0)e^{rx}=0$$

Since $e^{rx}$ never vanishes, the polynomial must vanish.

The roots of this polynomial, called the characteristic polynomial, if happen to be distinct, will give you independently linear functions. If a root had a multiplicity more than $n>1$, you take the functions like $e^{rx},xe^{rx},\cdots,x^{n-1}e^{rx}$ to obtain $n$ linearly independent functions.

We do all this because the solutions of a homogeneous ODE with constant coefficients is a vector space, in the sense that if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two solutions, then $\alpha f(x) + \beta g(x)$ is also a solution for any $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore, as a vector space, if we can find enough linearly independent solutions to the homogeneous ODE, we will be able to describe the space of solutions using the linearly independent solutions.

**Most importantly,** $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$ are in fact exponential functions in disguise, linked by Euler's formula $$e^{irt}=\cos(rt)+i\sin(rt)$$ and this is why they appear in the process of solving differential equations very often.

Comment: Why do we assume solutions have to be of this form? The point of the question is that we don't really assume, but show that any solution must be of this form.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: We assume that the solutions have to be of this form because $y'=ky$ implies $e^{kx}$. Then we get the characteristic equation which helps us derive $n$ linearly independent solutions. Since the space of the solutions is a vector space, these $n$ linearly independent solutions span a subspace. If this vector space happens to be of dimension $n$ (the order of the ODE), we're done. The issue of the dimension of the space is rather a subtle analysis question related to the Picard's existence theorem and I decided not to make the answer unnecessarily technical. :)

Comment: To be frank what you have done here is just describing a method to solve such equations and not exactly shown why the method works. The general theory of solution of such equations is difficult/technical, but the solution of a specific equation like $y'=ky$ or $y''=\pm ky$ is not very difficult as seen in the answer from David C. Ullrich. The scenario is similar to solving difference equations, but that is a somewhat simpler problem which can be solved by generating functions.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: The problem is not simpler for generation functions either. It's exactly the same. Or maybe even more difficult because I'm not aware of a similar theorem to Picard's existence theorem for that case. You still need to be able to solve the characteristic polynomial to do it even for generating functions. And I didn't describe a method, I attempted to outline the idea behind all this and give the OP an intuition about why we do what we do.

Comment: The generating functions approach shows how the characteristic equation comes into picture and why solving it is necessary for the partial fraction decomposition of the rational function. After partial fractions using Taylor series we get the coefficients which are of the form $a^n$ for root $a$ of characteristic equation. We don't have to assume a solution of the form $a^n$ at the start.

Comment: Using Taylor series with sequences is highly non-rigorous in its own for me. I know that there are Newton forward and backward difference formulae, but Taylor series is highly non-rigorous and non-intuitive for me. + The only non-rigorous part in my answer is to show that the vector space of solutions is of dimension of the order of the equation, which is related to Picard's existence theorem. I don't see how what you say tells us anything about that for difference equations. Anyway, if you want to continue the discussion, we should do it in chat in my opinion.

Comment: For differential equation $y''-3y'+2y=0$ we can write $(y'-2y)'-(y'-2y)=0$ and put $u=y'-2y$ to get $u'-u=0$ so that $u=ce^x$ and then solve $y'-2y=ce^x$. To solve this we can multiply the equation by $e^{-2x}$ and continue. This will exactly give the solution instead of assuming them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69971/discussion-between-paramanand-singh-and-stressed-out).

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: We are talking about a general homogeneous linear ODE of order $n$ with constant coefficients, not just particular instances of it. That's the essence of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Of course this is only true for $k>0$. Given that $k>0$, say $k=a^2$. Say $\alpha=y(0)$ and $\beta=y'(0)/a$, and define $$z(t) = y(t) - (\alpha\cos(at)+\beta\sin(at)).$$

Then it's easy to see that $$z''=-kz,\quad z(0)=z'(0)=0.$$

Here's the trick: The chain rule shows that $$(kz^2+(z')^2)'=2kzz'+2z'z''
=2z'(kz+z'')=0.$$So $z^2+(z')^2$ is constant; since $z(0)=z'(0)=0$ this shows that $$kz(t)^2+z'(t)^2=0$$for all $t$. And now since $kz^2\ge0$ and $(z')^2\ge0$ it follows that $kz^2=0=(z')^2.$ In particular $z(t)=0$, so $$y(t)=\alpha\cos(at)+\beta\sin(at).$$

**Fun Exercise 1.** Find the derivation of the differential equation describing the motion of weight suspended on a spring in a differential equations book, and contemplate how the proof above is inspired by conservation of energy.

**Fun Exercise 2.** Note that we've proved this:

> > If $y''+y=0$ and $y(0)=y'(0)=0$ then $y=0$.

Use this to prove the addition formulas for the sine and cosine.

Hint: Instead of  writing the addition formula for the sine as $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\dots$, write it in the form $$\sin(\alpha+t)-(\dots)=0.$$

Comment: This is exactly the kind of proof which is missing in introductory calculus textbooks. +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Yeah, I have to admit I kinda like it: A complete _proof_, totally elementary. Noticed the argument some years ago, this is the first chance I've had to "publish" it...

Comment: Incidentally the same proof is available on my blog post (see comments to the question). I first saw it as a problem in Spivak Calculus with hints provided.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thanks. For a minute just now I was thinking about a little Monthly article...

Answer (score 2):

The formal way is the theorem of **existence and uniqueness** of the solution.

**NOTE**

To solve without sin and cosine you can also plug in $y=e^{st}$

Answer (score 2):

As you've observed, you can guess that $\sin$ and $\cos$ work, and then invoke a theorem that says that once you've found two independent solutions the full set of solutions is the set of linear combinations.

If you didn't guess that but knew a little theory you would know that the solutions to a differential equation like this can be built from the complex roots of the quadratic equation $z^2 +1 = 0$, so they are $y = e^{ix}$ and $y=e^{-ix}$. Then use Euler's formula and combine them to find the trigonometric functions.